# Adding script that is not in a .js file in the <head> Magento 2 without using 'misc scripts' in admin

Tags: magento2, xml, head

I have some js script which I'd like to place in the  section of my Magento 2 site. I do **not** want to add in '**miscellaneous scripts**' section. I want to add this in **my themes default.xml** file. However, the below code in XML does not show on the frontend.

**default.xml**

```
<head>
    <css src="css/enmasse.css" />
    <script src="js::bootstrap.js"/>
    <script src="js::custom.js"/>
    <script>Some jquery script goes here</script>
</head>
```

**All other items here are called correctly** - so I know there's something wrong in the way I've added the final script element.

Can an edit be suggested to the above to get this working?

Comment: you cant add script logic inside xml file like your final line of script

Comment: In Magento 2 how do we go about this then Rakesh?

Comment: you can create simple js file and keep your content inside js file and call this js file in xml file

Comment: Tried that Rakesh and the script didn't work from within a js file. Presumably it 'needs' to be in the page.

Comment: any luck with this? I have same issue and need to add inline script to my head?